# Is Spine's XNA runtime missing an importer?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-content-pipeline, visual-studio, spine

I'm writing an XNA 4.0 game and use Spine for animation. Until now, I've been making spritesheets with Spine and using them with a custom animation class. I recently discovered there is an official Spine runtime for XNA. I've been trying to use it but encounter an error.

The closest I've come (after adding the runtime's classes to my project) is this error:

> Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "data\goblins.atlas". There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project.

Is there such an importer in the runtime and I simply missed it? If so, how can I get XNA to recognize it? If not, is there an alternative?

Comment: Does [the example](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/master/spine-xna/example) in [the repo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/master/spine-xna) work?

Comment: Nope. This is the one that throws this error!

Comment: Looks like a runtime bug then. (Examples are *supposed to work*! D:) Poke the devs through [gh issues](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/issues) or [the forum](http://esotericsoftware.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3). Nate is usually pretty quick to respond.

Comment: Thank you. I asked them. :) Oh and thanks for the edit as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! For those solutions that have a content project included you just have to add the data inside the main project and NOT the content. You must also make a copy of the data in the bin folder of the release.

Comment: Ah, so it isn't a bug after all? Good!